# How to use firestore orderBy but add undefined values as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetched workouts from firestore ordered by trained_on desc.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const database = firebase.firestore();
    const unsubscribe = database
      .collection("workouts")
      .where("uId", "==", user.uid)
      .orderBy("trained_on", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setWorkouts(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
        );
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

This is ignoring the entries with trained_on not set. When I create a new workout, there is no "trained_on".

How can a add the entries, where trained_on is undefined as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't query for a field that doesn't exist in firestore. The field "trained_on" needs to exist for a firestore index to be aware of it.

Quoting below the official documentation, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data

Limitations
Note the following restrictions for orderBy() clauses:

An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given fields. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given fields.

A possible workaround of this limitation would be that you fetch all the existing documents with a separate query & then manually subtract from them the ones from your query results. Or maybe you can include a marker value for "trained_on" field in required documents such as `null`. orderBy() clause works for `null` values.

Comment: The questions remains, though: How can a add the entries, where trained_on is undefined as well? A second query? What is best practice to do that? in the `.then()`?

Comment: A possible workaround of this limitation would be that you fetch all the existing documents with a separate query & then manually subtract from them the ones from your query results. Or maybe you can include a marker value for "trained_on" field in required documents such as `null`. orderBy() clause works for `null` values

Comment: That's the solution! Thank you