# Firestore fetching order by a field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using angular with firebase firestore db and trying to get the data in collection order by date attribtue. my current code without it is:

```
 this.core.readings = []
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.firestore, "readings"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      let data:any 
      data = doc.data()
      this.core.readings.push(data)
    });
```

i want  to add orderBy("date") but unable to see in docs etc how to apply this.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the reference from @aabdulahad the query might look something like this!

```
  this.core.readings = []
  const appRef = collection(this.firestore, "readings");
  const appQuery = query(appRef, orderBy("date"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(appQuery);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      let data:any 
      data = doc.data()
      this.core.readings.push(data)
    });
```

Comment: this works but it is ignoring the docs where the property is missing, how do i include those?

Comment: @MoblizeIT looks like its a [limitation of `orderBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015699/how-to-use-firestore-orderby-but-add-undefined-values-as-well)